# Connecting to 'All my Apps Page' url in itunes

Tags: ios, url, app-store, itunes

I'm finishing my app for distribution but I want my users to connect to my itunes page that will list all my apps.

From documentation, the advice is to use this type of link:

To send customers to a list of apps you have on the App Store:

> http://itunes.com/apps/developername

So I test it using an existing company in the appstore

> http://itunes.com/apps/ondemandworld (doesn't work)

But connecting to one of their apps and then using the appstore link to 'All their apps page' it works and is at this url:

> https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/ondemandworld/id342446989 (works)

1.Please could someone explain what that id number is  and where it can be found, so I can incorporate into my url to allow my users to link to 'All my apps' page.
i.e. I will try:

> ```
>     http://itunes.com/apps/developername/id[9digitnumber]
> ```

1. Can someone confirm that there is no way of directly testing your app url's until after your app submission has been accepted for distribution.

Comment: Use `SKStoreProductViewController` instead. It keeps the user in your app. You can pass your id and the user will see all of your apps.

Comment: I agree with rMaddy. That way, you retain the context of your app.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so what is the name of the id I use and could you tell me where I find it? So there is no way of directly testing your app url's until after your app submission has been accepted for distribution?

Comment: It seems the answer I was looking for was that unique 9 digit number is called a D-U-N-S Number which identifies business entities on a location-specific basis but enrolling as an individual not a company, means it is not required.